# Styling Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to implement styling on my Action Bar Sherlock on the following:

[image]

Basically the `actionbar overflow` is to be styled in regards to its background color. I did try the following approach.

```
   <style name="GCTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDown</item>
    </style> 

    <style name="MyDropDown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"> 
       <item name="android:popupBackground">#7D7D7D</item>
    </style>
```

I also did try implementing the `android:actionMenuTextColor` and also the `android:actionOverflowButton` but it says that API 11 or higher is required... Any idea on how this is to be implemented ? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but did you try [this tool?](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="GCTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> 
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDown</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00BFFF</item>
</style> 

<style name="MyDropDown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"> 
   <item name="android:popupBackground">#7D7D7D</item>
</style> 

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">  
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#7D7D7D</item> 
</style>
```